# When generating a random image url using an API, why do I need to randomise the dimensions?

Tags: javascript

I was making an example loading bar using https://source.unsplash.com/ to generate a new image source on a click event.

Source code & example [here](https://codepen.io/theomjones/pen/wPWPJz?editors=0010).

On each button click event I reapplied the `src` attribute to the image. The image did not change. This same behaviour occurred when creating an image element and applying the `src` attribute to that, then appending it to the document.

To fix it I generated a random number and applied to to the second dimension at the end of the url on each click event.

Why does this behaviour occur?

A simplified version of what I did first (didn't work):

```
// onclick = getPhoto()
function getPhoto() {
  img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/3000x3000';
}
```

What I tried second (worked):

```
function getPhoto() {
  img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/3000x3000' +
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) +
  2800;
}
```

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Makes sense, also works if you just add a random number as a query at the end of the url. Cheers